# Laravel Forge Deployment Branch Doesn't Exist

Tags: git

I have a `Laravel` site that is currently deploying from the `develop` branch. 
This works. But I want this site to pull from the `master` branch. 
When I attempt to do this I get an error:

> "That branch does not exist."

The `master` branch does exist however, it is not the default branch on the repository. Could that be the issue? Any help you provide is appreciated, thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What command do you run?